# Consequences of VIM's binary mode

Tags: vim

My recipe for saving files in `vim` without the end of file newline is:

```
:set binary
:set noeol
:wq
```

The fact that noeol does nothing without binary mode is weird on itself. But reading the `:help binary` i'm still unsure of somethings there.

> ```
>  When this option is switched on a few
>         options will be changed (also when it already was on):
>                 'textwidth'  will be set to 0
>                 'wrapmargin' will be set to 0
>                 'modeline'   will be off
>                 'expandtab'  will be off
>         Also, 'fileformat' and 'fileformats' options will not be used, the
>         file is read and written like 'fileformat' was "unix" (a single <NL>
>         separates lines).
>         The 'fileencoding' and 'fileencodings' options will not be used, the
>         file is read without conversion.
>         NOTE: When you start editing a(nother) file while the 'bin' option is
>         on, settings from autocommands may change the settings again (e.g.,
>         'textwidth'), causing trouble when editing.  You might want to set
>         'bin' again when the file has been loaded.
> ```

i can still see UTF8 chars, so fileencoding is not totally gone. I never used expandtab (use tabs to ident, but even if i didn't, expandtabs is just wrong). But besides that, what else could happen in practice?

i'm tired of that new line at the end of files and considering opening all files in binary mode and with noeol set by default. Am I in for lots of trouble?

Comment: This answer tries to explain the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16224292/593264 In short, the EOL character is supposed to mark the end of line, and other editors "wrongly" interpret this as there being a new line after the EOL character. Seen from a different angle, the extra line is beneficial in other editors because you would otherwise have to move to the end of the line and press enter, whereas in vi(m) you of course just press `o` to open a new line. Or put even more differently, do you have a problem with the extra line, beyond cosmetical reasons?

Comment: yep, text is text. I would like to have full control. As you said on other editors I can simply go there and press enter or delete the line break. in vim it is beyond me. But if you want more practical examples, i can list a few text to binary formats. Or more abound, the php issue that inserts that line break since it is technically *after* the `?>` tag and so is part of the content to be output, which will cause problems if it is in a include that is required before your code that will deal with cookies or other headers.

Comment: Ah! So that's the actual problem. The recommended solution to that is to simply omit the `?>` which eliminates that problem in a more controllable way. Yes, that is valid PHP.

Comment: This was one of the examples. Most editors leave that last line break out, so it results in one extra change i have to commit on my version control softwares. nothing big, as the php is not big, but it bothers the OCD in me.

Comment: Well, as far as vi(m) is concerned, the syntax for a line is text followed by a line terminator. Much like how a statement in c is terminated by `;` or a sentence in English is terminated by `.`. The terminator is integral to the object. As far as vi(m) is concerned, a line without a terminator is syntactically invalid text, and you have to enable binary mode to edit your non-text file the way you want. vi(m) sees lines as entities, whereas other editors put keystrokes (e.g. enter) into a buffer as individual characters (e.g. `\n`). It's a difference in philosophy and not a haphazard decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't encounter arbitrary encodings (i.e. either all ASCII or the encoding matching your Vim's), and aren't bothered by the `^M` in files with Window file endings, you approach should work just fine.

Vim wasn't meant to edit such files (the Unix standpoint is they are incomplete), therefore it's hard to do. However, my [PreserveNoEOL plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4550) tries to make that more comfortable, so you don't have to worry about the mechanics.

Comment: Wow that's a huge extension. I will read it and give it a try. I've used some others ones in the past. my grip with most of them is that they usually just do that (:binary :noeol) so they have the same consequences, or they just wipe the last byte of the file after save. in both cases i'm not seeing the changes that i'm committing to the file system while editing.

Answer (score 0):

since vim 7.4, you can use `:set nofixeol`

https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27fixeol%27